# Understanding the Master Theorem - Determining the levels of recursion

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to understand the proof for the Master Theorem. I have started by unwinding the following recurrence in order to find the total running time of an algorithm whose time complexity can be modelled by the following recurrence:

$$
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are both integers, $a >= 1, b > 1$ and $f(n) > 0$

I understand that at level 'j' of the recursion, the number of subproblems is $a^j$, with each subproblem having a size of $n/b^j$, and each subproblem taking time at most $f(n/b^j)$. Therefore, level 'j' contributes a total of at most $a^j*f(n/b^j)$ to the total running time.

I have read that there are $\log_bn$ levels of recursion for an algorithm that follows the above recurrence. However, I don't understand how the number of levels of recursion is derived to be $\log_bn$. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The level of recursions should rather be

- $\lceil \log_b n \rceil$

You can see this quite easily if you consider the special cases $n=b^m$:

- $n = b^1 \Rightarrow 1$ recursion $\Rightarrow 1 = \log_b b$.

Obviously you need also for $1\leq n < b$ at least $1$ round. So, the level of recursions here is $\lceil \log_b n \rceil$.

Similarly:

- $n = b^m \Rightarrow m$ recursions $\Rightarrow m = \log_b n$

For $b^{m-1} +1 \leq n < b^m$ you also have $m = \lceil \log_b n \rceil$ recursions, because after $m-1$ recursions there are still $b \geq n-b^{m-1}>0$ tasks left to be solved.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that you reach the base case of the recursion when the problem of size 'n' has been reduced to a problem of size 'b'?

Comment: @ceno980 This is rather a wording question of what you mean by size. Important is that "the last $b$" tasks are somehow "elementary" in the sense that they won't be broken up further.

Comment: For the special case where n = b where there is one round of recursion, would it be correct to say that the size of each subproblem will be 1, and there will be 'a' subproblems? Am I correct in saying that the base case of the recursion is reached when the problem of size 'n' is reduced to a problem of size 1?

Comment: Yes. If you interpret "size 1" as that it cannot be further handled by the algorithm (except for returning a result).